# Win32, C++: Sending email in Windows 10 by invoking default mail client

Tags: c++, email, winapi, windows-10

There are number of posts in Stackoverflow as well as many other websites which show how to send an email with an attachment by invoking the default mail client. Pretty much the same when you right click on any file in Windows Explorer and from the context menu choosing Send to->Mail recipient.

Lot of these samples I found online use MAPI, but none of them work. There are also examples that use ShellExecute and use the mailto: protocol. The latter works for me but not when I try to send an attachment. The attachment simply does not show up in Outlook's New Mail window. The MAPI examples once again don't work with attachments. I get weird errors like whether I would like to allow or deny.

If Windows is able to do it, that means other apps should be able to do it too. Does anyone know which API to use that works for Windows 10?

Comment: I realize you've tagged C++, but if you can leverage it, .NET's System.Net.Mail works great - and fully supports attachments.

Comment: Whether you would like to allow or deny sounds like a security prompt to me rather than a weird error.

Comment: @GSerg, well even after I allow it, it does not proceed. And the API call returns 0, which mean no error...

Comment: @STLDeveloper, I'm pretty sure .Net will work:) the problem is that my app is in Qt and I don't want to add a dependency to .Net.

Comment: It's not clear to me that Windows can do it with an arbitrary mail client.  The SendTo in Explorer invokes a COM object that works with various flavors of Outlook.  https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3839/SendTo-mail-recipient

Comment: MAPI most certainly can handle attachments. I have an app that sends emails containing attached zips of log files via MAPI, and it works just fine.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, I'm not talking about sending an email from within an app, I'm talking about invoking the mail client with an attachment.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy, I am getting an access violation error when I try to execute your code at the following statement:
pDropTarget->Drop(pDataObject, MK_LBUTTON, pt, &dwEffect);

Comment: @armanali:  Not my code.  I was citing that as a source of information about how SendTo works with Outlook.

Comment: It's not entirely clear form the question, what you are really trying to accomplish. Do you want to send an email, or do you want to open the default email client UI?

Comment: [Part 1](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20080724-00/?p=21483) and [Part 2](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20080725-00/?p=21473) might or might not be useful.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy, I've posted the answer to the question. Didn't have to go through COM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the code that works. It's mixed with Qt stuff, but Qt classes are later converted to STL in the code. The reason that my code was not working previously was because I was setting lpszPathName to the path of the attachment and lpszFileName to the filename of the attachment. Path has to be set to the full path including the filename, and filename should be set to whatever we want to be displayed as the name of the attachment in the email client. It may be just the filename, it may be something else.

```
bool InvokeDefaultEmailClient(HWND hwndParent, const QStringList 
                             &attachmentFilenames, const QString &subject)
{
    HINSTANCE hInst = LoadLibraryW(L"mapi32.dll");
    if (!hInst) {
        return false;
    }

    ULONG(PASCAL *SendMail)(ULONG, ULONG_PTR, MapiMessageW*, FLAGS, ULONG);
    (FARPROC&)SendMail = GetProcAddress(hInst, "MAPISendMailW");

    if (!SendMail) {
        return false;
    }

    std::vector<std::wstring> attachmentFilenamesVector;
    for(int i=0; i<attachmentFilenames.size(); ++i) {
        QString filename = attachmentFilenames[i];
        attachmentFilenamesVector.push_back(filename.toStdWString());
    }

    QVector<MapiFileDescW> fileDescs;
    for (int i = 0; i < attachmentFilenamesVector.size(); ++i) {
        MapiFileDescW fileDesc;
        ZeroMemory(&fileDesc, sizeof(fileDesc));
        fileDesc.nPosition = (ULONG)-1;
        fileDesc.lpszPathName = (TCHAR*)attachmentFilenamesVector[i].c_str();
        fileDesc.lpszFileName = (TCHAR*)attachmentFilenamesVector[i].c_str();
        fileDescs.push_back(fileDesc);
    }

    MapiMessageW message;
    ZeroMemory(&message, sizeof(message));
    message.lpszSubject = (TCHAR*)subject.toStdString().c_str();
    message.nFileCount = fileDescs.size();
    message.lpFiles = fileDescs.data();

    int error = SendMail(0, (ULONG_PTR)hwndParent, &message, MAPI_LOGON_UI | MAPI_DIALOG, 0);

    if (error != SUCCESS_SUCCESS && error != MAPI_USER_ABORT && error != MAPI_E_LOGIN_FAILURE) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```